# Start Activity with smaller context?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to start a new Activity and I do it like this in the mainActivity:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent startHeroStats = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), HeroStats.class);
            startActivity(startHeroStats);
        }
    });
```

Whenever I try to start the activity by clicking on one of the Items the application crashes with the error "FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION". I read that the context is too huge (it probably contains an imageView), but I don't even need to pass any data from my mainActivity to the other one. 
Help is much appreciated.

Comment: You can use `YourActivityName.this` for the `Context`. But paste your entire stacktrace from the crash so we can help you.

Comment: @codeMagic Thanks for offering help, figured it out myself. I didnt need to pass on data, so I just used the context of some random TextView. ApplicationContext and the other contained pictures which is why they were so big.